# Are built-in types implementations avaliable in Python?

Tags: python, cpython

It's easy to find implementation of any library module in python (you just go to CPython repository on Github: https://github.com/python/cpython/), but where could I find implementations of build-in CPython types? It's important for example to prove that **complex** build-in type is inherited from **numbers.Complex** abc. Or it is also could be useful to explore attributes of **function** type.

Comment: The source for the built-in types are in the same repository, of course: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/complexobject.c for example.

Comment: The fact that `complex` is a subclass of `numbers.Complex` comes from the [`numbers` modules itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/numbers.py#L144), not the definition of the type.